# Is there any way to translate SQL from one DB to another?

Tags: sql

For example, select some rows from table:

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM PERSONS
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PERSONS 
LIMIT 5
```

Oracle:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PERSONS 
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If Python is an option for you, the `sqlalchemy` package is designed for this by proving a common interface across database engines.

Comment: @S3DEV Thank you very much.Is there any other way to solve this problem without using ORM?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any solution that you wanted to build yourself would require some level of coding - from simple search-and-replace to vba/python/etc.

However, for anything except the simplest SQL this would be a very complicated undertaking. SQL is very flexible in the way statements can be written and combined into more complex statements - so writing a process that “understands” the parts of a SQL statement (which would be a pre-requisite for translating SQL) is definitely not trivial.

To illustrate this, if this was a simple exercise then there would be lots of solutions out there but in fact there is only one (that I’m aware of) that claims to be able to do this type of thing: sqlparser.com

Answer (score 1):

Your particularly problem has been fixed.  All three databases that you mention now support the SQL Standard `offset`/`fetch` syntax -- although SQL Server requires the `offset` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PERSONS
OFFSET 0 FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```